# Does Texmaker have "open containing folder" option

Tags: texmaker

I've looked up the options in Texmaker but it doesn't seem it has this feature "open containing folder". Is there an option regarding this matter?

Comment: No there isn't. I try to build a user command that do this (this is easy) but my explorer doesn't work fine so it doesn't work

Comment: @touhami, thanks. Please transfer the comment to an answer so that I can accept it.

Comment: I will try to share the idea my be it works for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Notes** Following Texmaker's documentation the character **`!` represents the current directory** so the idea is to use a user command `explorer.exe !` (under windows or equivalent for other platforms). Indeed, if i try command `pdflatex !/myfile.tex` where `myfile.tex` is a file in current directory the command works fine and i get the file compiled but I can't get it to work with `explorer.exe`

---

Here is a solution (**under windows**)

Make a batch file `myexplorer.bat` with contents:

```
explorer.exe %~dp1
```

1. in Texmker go to menu: `User-->User commands-->Edit user commands`
2. paste this command `<PathOfMyBatch>\myexplorer.bat %.tex`

---

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3):

*So, turns out this question wasn't about TeXStudio (which is what this answer is regarding) at all! I'm going to leave this here anyways, as a reminder for me to read the title next time...*

## macOS or Linux

In macOS, go to `Preferences -> Build -> User Commands`.
Add a new command called "open working directory" whose contents is simply

```
open .
```

[image: Build section in TeXStudio preference window]

You can run the command from `Tools -> User -> open working directory`.

[image]

I assume the process is identical (except for menu layout perhaps) on Linux.

## Windows

Same as above, but the command is now

```
start !
```

If @touhami is right about TeXStudio using `!` to represent the current directory, or try

```
start .
```

If [this website](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/stupid-geek-tricks-open-an-explorer-window-from-the-command-prompts-current-directory/) is to be trusted:

> The period is used in the Command Prompt as a shorthand for the current folder, so this will open the current folder in File Explorer.

Which would match with my understanding...

Comment: (+1) for the effort. In Windows, opening the current folder is done via `start .`.

Comment: Although not exactly Texmaker...

Comment: Ha! I found this question when searching for a similar function for TeXStudio... Guess I read the title the way I wanted to instead of actually reading it...

Comment: What worked for me under Windows: `explorer.exe .`

Answer (score 0):

For me, using Texstudio on Windows, the working command is

```
cmd.exe /c "start ."
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Where should this command be issued?

Answer (score 0):

For Texmaker in Ubuntu (Linux), add a User Command (Alt+U+C)

> nautilus .

[image]